# Mysql vs mysqld vs mysql-server

Tags: apt, mysql

I had a project that required a `MySQL` server, so I installed it using...

`apt install MySQL-server`

Before realizing that Ubuntu already had a `MySQLd` server running in `systemd`. So I uninstalled `MySQL-server`.

But I cant login into it, and when I tried to install `MySQL-server` it kept having errors which I assume are from the binaries colliding? As well as I didn't have the password.

What is the difference between the three? I simply want to connect to a database that is started on boot. If I can use the one already installed how do i login as I do not have the password.

other information

`which mysql` -> /usr/bin/mysql
`which mysqld` -> /usr/sbin/mysqld

Comment: Can you please show the error it will help us to debug the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all it must be cleared out that `MySql-Server`, as its name implies, is a Server program that is used to persist the data and provide a query interface for it. But `mysql` is a client program which can be used to interact with your server (locally or remotely).

Having said this and by reading [man pages](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/noble/en/man1/mysql.1.html), you can understand that:

- `mysqld` is the server executable (one of them)
- `mysql` is the command line client
- `mysqladmin` is a maintenance or administrative utility

I hope this information help you.